# How to get the path of the sketch in Processing ? (dataPath not working)

Tags: java, processing

Using Processing 3-0-1 (not updated yet), I have a problem with the dataPath() function.

My code :

```
final String path = dataPath("");
//...
void setup(){
  //...
  println(path);
  //...
}
```

This displays in the console :

> /media/ubuntu/Expansion Drive/Programmation/Java/Processing/Ubuntu/processing-3.0.1/null/data

but it should display (according to the Documentation and my tries in other projects) :

> /media/ubuntu/Expansion Drive/Programmation/Java/Processing/Projets/Time_Fighter/data

So it seems it's returning a path the Processing instead of a path to my project ? Plus, why is there a 'null' ?

**The question is, do you know a way that would work to have the path of my sketch ?**

**PS.**
A friend of mine proposed to use the File class instead, I had this result :

```
File file = new File("data");
//...
void setup(){
  //...
  file.getAbsolutePath();
  //...
}
```

Which returned :

> /media/ubuntu/Expansion Drive/Programmation/Java/Processing/Ubuntu/processing-3.0.1/data

**PPS.**
I'm using Ubuntu (Mate)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `dataPath()` function. You should use the `sketchPath()` function.

From [the Processing source for `dataPath()`](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java):

```
/**
   * <b>This function almost certainly does not do the thing you want it to.</b>
   * The data path is handled differently on each platform, and should not be
   * considered a location to write files. It should also not be assumed that
   * this location can be read from or listed. This function is used internally
   * as a possible location for reading files. It's still "public" as a
   * holdover from earlier code.
   * <p>
   * Libraries should use createInput() to get an InputStream or createOutput()
   * to get an OutputStream. sketchPath() can be used to get a location
   * relative to the sketch. Again, <b>do not</b> use this to get relative
   * locations of files. You'll be disappointed when your app runs on different
   * platforms.
   */
  public String dataPath(String where) {
    return dataFile(where).getAbsolutePath();
  }
```

And here's `sketchPath()`:

```
/**
   * Prepend the sketch folder path to the filename (or path) that is
   * passed in. External libraries should use this function to save to
   * the sketch folder.
   * <p/>
   * Note that when running as an applet inside a web browser,
   * the sketchPath will be set to null, because security restrictions
   * prevent applets from accessing that information.
   * <p/>
   * This will also cause an error if the sketch is not inited properly,
   * meaning that init() was never called on the PApplet when hosted
   * my some other main() or by other code. For proper use of init(),
   * see the examples in the main description text for PApplet.
   */
  public String sketchPath(String where) {
    if (sketchPath() == null) {
      return where;
    }
    // isAbsolute() could throw an access exception, but so will writing
    // to the local disk using the sketch path, so this is safe here.
    // for 0120, added a try/catch anyways.
    try {
      if (new File(where).isAbsolute()) return where;
    } catch (Exception e) { }

    return sketchPath() + File.separator + where;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`sketchPath()` only works after `setup()`, you can't do

```
String path = sketchPath();
setup() {
}
```

Instead, you need to do:

```
String path;
setup() {
  path = sketchPath();
}
```

(Processing 3.5.4)